# can't redirect python script output to stdout

Tags: python, windows, shell, cmd

1. Windows 7
2. Python 3.5
3. Google CppLint.py

   python C:\dev\tools\cpplint.py my_source.cpp > cpplint.tasks

creates empty output file, and just prints the results into console

pls assist

Comment: You are redirecting just std:out , what if what You see in console is std:err ?
As I see on github, cppLint.py writes to `sys.stderr.write`

Comment: you are right - looked at that google py script , stderr is there

Comment: Try `python C:\dev\tools\cpplint.py my_source.cpp > cpplint.tasks 2>&1` to redirect `stdout` to "cpplint.tasks" and `stderr` to `stdout` (i.e. the same file).

Comment: yes, it works, many thanks!